# Alternative flow in usecase

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram, domain-model

If u have a use case with an alternative flow, and in that flow there is need for some new classes and methods should you add those classes to the main domain model and sequence diagram or should u create an alternate domain model?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this, preferably with an example?

Comment: I think we'd be assuming a bunch of things if we gave an answer, which some context would help with, especially about your intent for the models you already have and why you are considering to not just update them.

Answer (score 0):

Domain model describes all business entities that are relevant, so you should include whatever is needed. Also hardly ever a domain is limited to classes of just one use case.
Having said that, let me add that hardly ever the whole domain can be shown on a single class diagram. Usually you'll divide it into smaller parts that are somehow related. Of course some classes will be on more than one diagram. Note that all your classes and all relationships shown on any class diagram (even if shown on one but hidden on other diagram) pose your domain.
Of course there might be class diagrams on different level of modeling that are not a direct part off business model. All I wrote is respective only to business level analysis and diagrams.